# Drawing axes using pstricks

Tags: pstricks

How can I draw something like the one  shown in the attachment in LaTeX?

[image: graph]

I have heard about `pstricks`, but I am not familiar with it. If there is any good tutorial about it I will appreciate if you share it with me.

Comment: I would use tikz http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf or pgfplots http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots.

Answer (score 7):

I choosed a simple function. Run with `xelatex` or the sequence `latex`->`dvips`->s2pdf`or use package`auto-pst-pdf`and run with`pdflatex --shell-escape`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=1.3}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(7,4)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(7,4)[$x$,-90][$\mu(x)$,180]
\psplot[algebraic]{0}{6.5}{(2*x-1)/(x+4)+1}
\multido{\iA=0+1}{7}{%
  \psline[arrows=-*,linestyle=dashed](\iA,0)(* {\iA} {(2*x-1)/(x+4)+1})}
\multido{\iA=1+1,\iB=5+-1}{5}{\psxTick(\iA){x-\iB h}}
\psxTick(0){0}\psxTick(6){x}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]